# Hydronic floor floor system problem

Tags: plumbing, hvac, heating, hydronic

Here's a picture of my hydronic floor heating system with three zones.
[image]

A tech came out and told me that the feeder was bad. He also told me that on the controller board everything's working as it should. I had the feeder replaced. Right now, only one of the three zones is working. The other two (one on the same level and the other floor up) are not working. I'm not hearing the pumps turn on.

Is it fairly certain that the pumps aren't working and need to be replaced? Or is there some other test I can perform right now to gather more information?

Comment: My first step would be to power the pumps directly - that tests the pump and for flow.

Comment: @SolarMike - I'd like to do that, but how do I do that? I'm thinking: turn the power off to the relay board and apply 120V to the corresponding leads inside the control panel?

Comment: "power the pumps directly" means power the pumps directly, NOT through any board or remote connection.

Comment: @SolarMike So open the pump's junction box, disconnect from the board and apply 120V?

Comment: Based on your questions, you should get that electrician/tech back.

Comment: @SolarMike I realize I don't much, but I'm hoping to learn here.

Comment: @SolarMike that seems like a lot of trouble and sorta risky.  I think simply measuring at the pumps to see if they get power is much more simple and safer.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson are you assuming that the OP has a good multimeter and knows how to use it competently? Personally I have 2 - both good, one by Fluke and one by Avo.

Comment: @SolarMike I have a good multimeter and I know how to use it competently. I have confirmed that the pumps receive 120V but don't turn on.

Comment: So, broken neutral or is the control board switching neutral? You should be able to establish which with your meter.

Comment: 120V between the supply terminals and no brrr, that means the pump is bad.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a lot of things causing this, all you can do is trace it down.  Don't just start throwing parts it without knowing what's causing it.  OK, here's my starter list:

1. Be sure the pumps are actually getting power.  If not, the problem is upstream, could be a bad control board (in spite of what your tech told you), or bad relays  (unlikely). The circ pumps are usually very reliable and unlikely to fail, esp. 3 at once.
2. Check the thermostats to ensure 2 things:  There is indeed a **call for heat** and that it shows "system on" or similar.  Some tstats wired or wireless require batteries that may need to be replaced.
3. Make sure the system has been purged of all air and that the air vent on the top of your primary loop is working

A few more pics of the plumbing layout might help us give you better answers/suggestions. Also could you clarify what you mean by a "feeder pump"?  is that the main circulator pump on the primary loop?

Comment: By feeder I mean the pressure valve (with the blue tag). I confirmed that the pumps are getting power when the tstat calls for heat. How do I make sure that the system has been purged of air and that the air vent on the top is working?

Comment: @Wynne I don't yet know enough about your system, but you probably have some manifolds providing hot water to the floors in various loops, one manifold for each zone, most likely.  They usually have automatic air release devices on them that can go bad.  Many times they can be operated manually, completely depends upon the brand and model of the manifold. Regarding the air release at the top of the main loop, it's probably working OK, since at least one zone is working.  I'm getting to the end of my expertise here, not a pro!   ...continued below...

Comment: @Wynne ...continued: I DK  If you have manifolds or each zone is a direct feed from a circ pump.  manifolds are often buried in walls behind access panels and can be hard to locate.  They can also clog up with minerals, depending upon the water quality that supplied the system.   I fought that for years at my house, having to do repeated flushing s of the system to clear the deposits created by my poor water quality.

At the end of the day,   if the pumps are getting power and not running, maybe it is as simple as they went bad.  Who knows?